# If Planck’s constant were larger would photons of light of the same frequency be more energetic or less energetic?

Tags: energy, visible-light, photons, physical-chemistry

If Planck’s constant were larger would photons of light that have the same frequency be more energetic or less energetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy of a wave is described by $E=hf$. If frequency is held constant and $h$ is increased, then $E$ must also increase. So it would be more energetic.

Comment: Since the energy of a photon and the frequency of a photon are proportional does that mean that since the energy is increasing the frequency would also increase?

Comment: @Inperitus What do you mean by "since the energy is increasing"? All it means is that a photon with a higher energy will have a higher frequency, and vice versa.

Comment: You said that "If frequency is held constant" so I assumed you meant that f is not increasing, but when E increases doesn't that also mean that f is increasing?

Comment: @Inperitus Normally yes, since $h$ is a constant, but in this context I held $f$ constant instead and increased $h$ because that's what the question was asking about.